# Reactjs + Webpack 2.x + react-router 4.x after bundled without error, use html src bundle.js, css recognised., but no components rendered out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-2, react-router-v4

As the title says, I'm using webpack 2.x, react-router v4, bundling successful, no errors, yet open index.html, not showing exactly like the website. Just when bundling separately not working. Been scratching my head for a week. No Errors were produced no clue whats the problem.. hoping someone can help.. Thanks in advance..

When using webpack-dev-server, it works normal, every components rendered.

Situation: bundled successfully without errors. bundle.js, some images, and a font folder files produced in /public folder. index.html with src bundle.js. double clicked it. the css part of the website recognised, javascript parts nothing..
using chrome reacttools it shows like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Router history={...etcs}>
  <App>
   <Switch>
    null
   </Switch>
  </App>
 </Router>
</BrowserRouter>
```

my folder hierarchy:
[Folder Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypt0q.jpg)

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "fei-react",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Fei's official business website",
  "main": "app.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --port 9999"
  },
  "author": "Albert Chai",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "react": "^15.*",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.*",
    "react-dom": "^15.*",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0-beta.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aphrodite": "^1.*",
    "babel-core": "^6.*",
    "babel-loader": "^6.*",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.*",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.*",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.*",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.*",
    "css-loader": "^*",
    "file-loader": "^*",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.*",
    "fullpage-react": "^2.*",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^*",
    "jquery": "^3.*",
    "node-sass": "^4.*",
    "react-hot-loader": "^*",
    "react-images": "^0.*",
    "react-linkify": "^0.*",
    "react-photo-gallery": "^5.*",
    "sass-loader": "^*",
    "script-loader": "^*",
    "style-loader": "^*",
    "url-loader": "^*",
    "webpack": "^2.*",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.*"
  }
}
```

my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry:  "./app.jsx",

  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
  },

  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './public'
  },


  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        '$': 'jquery',
        'jQuery': 'jquery'
      }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],


  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "/"), "node_modules"],

    alias: {
      About: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/pages/About.jsx'),
      Contact: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/pages/Contact.jsx'),
      Projects: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/pages/Projects.jsx'),
      Content: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/pages/Content.jsx'),
      Main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/Main.jsx'),
      Loader: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/pages/Loader.jsx'),
      Logo: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/Logo.jsx'),
      LogoA: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/LogoA.jsx'),
      ArrowButton: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/ArrowButton.jsx'),
      EmailUser: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/EmailUser.jsx'),
      applicationStyles: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/styles/app.scss'),
      applicationFonts: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/fonts/fonts.scss'),
      fullreactNorm: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/normalize.css'),
      fullreactSke: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/skeleton.css'),
      exampleStyles: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/exampleStyles.scss')
    },
    extensions: ['.css','.scss', '.js', '.jsx']
  },

module: {
  rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['react-hot-loader','babel-loader']
      },
        {
            test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: "file-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: "url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000"
        },
        {
            test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]"
        },
        {
            test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
        },
        {
            test: /\.gif/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/gif"
        },
        {
            test: /\.jpg/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/jpg"
        },
        {
            test: /\.png/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png"
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

my babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env","react"
  ]
}
```

my react-router setting within app.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var {Route, Router, Switch, BrowserRouter} = require('react-router-dom');
var Main = require('Main');
var Content = require('Content');
var About = require('About');
var Contact = require('Contact');

// App css
require('style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!applicationStyles')
require('style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!exampleStyles')   

// App font
require('style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!applicationFonts')

const App = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={About} />
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
    <Route path="/content" component={Content} />
  </Switch>
)

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Not sure what other information needed. However i have uploaded the whole project on github. this is the website 
https://github.com/triple1c86/FeiReactWebsite

Please help.. search all over the internet and this stackoverflow, cant seems to find any answer.. Thanks again

Comment: Check this repo out, it demonstrates a [real-world Webpack 2 + React Router 4 setup](https://github.com/ModusCreateOrg/budgeting-sample-app-webpack2)

Comment: I cannot bundle the project with the github you provided.

> Error: Module '/data/web/tests/FeiReactWebsite/node_modules/react-hot-loader/index.js' is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)

Are you sure you are

Comment: You should block the versions of you dependencies. It might be a conflict between incompatible version of webpack and a loader for example.